# Installing and testing the Erlang bindings for Apache Thrift in OS X Mavericks with Homebrew

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew, thrift

While installing `thrift` with Homebrew in OS X Mavericks, I am not sure the Erlang bindings are getting correctly installed, and I strongly believe they are not.

The command I am running is this:

```
brew install thrift --with-erlang
```

I have tried it with `--with-python` and it seems to install additional files; however, it doesn't appear to do so in the case of Erlang.  Also, I don't really know how to test the installation in Erlang to make sure that I am correct.

If this provides any additional insight, the Erlang version I have installed is the `.pkg` binaries available from Erlang Solutions (the link is currently down).

What should I do to install the Erlang thrift bindings and make sure they work?

Thanks very much!

Comment: There were some issues with homebrew, IIRC. Try searching JIRA and/or the mailing list archives, or try asking there. I don't have the details at hand. Sorry.

Comment: OK.  So I would think that the best way to install it is from source, as specified in the Thrift webpage?

Comment: If you want a stable version, use the appropriate download links. You are free to try the current source trunk, of course. The 0.9.1 release is quite a few months old now, so it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything is installed correctly, a `make all` or `make check` in the Erlang `lib` folder should do.

In that folder, there's also a README file with further instructions and examples:
https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/erl/README.md

> ```
> Example session using thrift_client:
>
> 1> {ok, C0} = thrift_client_util:new("localhost", 9090, thriftTest_thrift, []), ok.
> ok
> 2> {C1, R1} = thrift_client:call(C0, testVoid, []), R1.
> {ok,ok}
> 3> {C2, R2} = thrift_client:call(C1, testVoid, [asdf]), R2.
> {error,{bad_args,testVoid,[asdf]}}
> 4> {C3, R3} = thrift_client:call(C2, testI32, [123]), R3.
> {ok,123}
> 5> {C4, R4} = thrift_client:call(C3, testOneway, [1]), R4.
> {ok,ok}
> 6> {C5, R5} = thrift_client:call(C4, testXception, ["foo"]), R5.
> {error,{no_function,testXception}}
> 7> {C6, R6} = thrift_client:call(C5, testException, ["foo"]), R6.
> {ok,ok}
> 8> {C7, R7} = (catch thrift_client:call(C6, testException, ["Xception"])), R7.
> {exception,{xception,1001,<<"Xception">>}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Please, what do you mean the Erlang `lib` folder?  Is that inside of the Thrift installation?  Any idea where that might be located?

Comment: Yes, inside the source tree. Please follow the GitHub link.